# Which is right?, separation of variables, differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I've recently found two explanations on how to solve this IVP, 
One is wrong , one is not. Which one is which? and more importantly why ?

There's free treasure for getting the right answer ^^

For $X'(t)= (X^2)t,$

and Initial Conditions $X(o)=X_o,$

Does $X(t)= -2/(t^2+c) \Longrightarrow X(t)= -2/(t^2-2/X_o)$ as $C=-2/X_o$

Or does $X(t)= -2/(t^2+2c) \Longrightarrow X(t)=-2/(t^2-2X_o)$ as $C=-X_o$?

on second thoughts , treasure that is free isn't very valuable , so an imaginary high five should suffice as a prize.

Comment: If you really know that one of them is not wrong, then how is it that you don't know which one?

Comment: The second is not correct.

Comment: Why is the tag "Separation of Variables" assigned to this post?

Comment: I'm mainly asking why,

Comment: And separation of variables is the method that my quoted example uses,

Comment: Why is that Mr  Sala  Fatima ? my  good sir

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to check:

1. Make sure the answer satisfies the initial condition.
2. Make sure the answer satisfies the differential equation.

In your question, (1) will fail for one of the answers -- which one?

As for your treasure comments, I consider them impolite.

**UPDATE**

So you have $$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2 t$$ which separates into $x^{-2}dx = tdt$ and integrates out to $$-x^{-1} = \frac{t^2}{2} + C$$ which simplifies to
$$
x(t) = - \frac{1}{t^2/2+C} = \frac{-2}{t^2+2C}
$$
and the initial condition implies
$$
x_0 = x(0) = \frac{-2}{2C} = -1/C
$$
so $C = -1/x_0$ and the final form would be
$$
x(t) = \frac{-2}{t^2-2/x_0} = \frac{2x_0}{2-x_0t^2}
$$

Comment: I know which one, the second line won't work ,  I just don't know why

Comment: Also , Impolite??  No imaginary high fives for you :P

Comment: To be more clear, I'm unsure as to where and how during the integration that the first line appears,  instead of the second.

Comment: @JeffTaffleSticks see update

Comment: Many thanks,  my head has been frazzled, as I ended up spending a lot of time trying to clarify it to myself ,   I do owe you an  i(high)5  despite my earlier comments , and once again, cheers ^^